# Catch an error and return a new type in RxJava2

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, reactivex

I have a stream:

```
val symbols: Single<List<Symbol>>
```

Now I want to transform the stream into a UI State with map():

```
private fun cool(): Single<SymbolContract.State> =
    symbols.map { SymbolContract.State.Symbols(it) }
```

What I want to do is catch an error on the upstream `symbols` single, so that I can catch any errors and then return `SymbolContract.State.GeneralError()`.

I want something like a `onErrorMap()` or something. Unfortunately, putting `onErrorResumeItem` on `symbols` doesn't work because it needs to return a `List<Symbol>`.

I can think of a few ugly ways to do this, but what's the cleanest?

Comment: I guess you meant `onErrorReturnItem` since `onErrorResumeItem` does not exist. In any case, why would it return a List of Symbols? `onErrorReturnItem` will return a `SymbolContract.State`.

Comment: It has to return the same type that the stream returns

Comment: I don't get anything. If you change the stream with map, the current stream must return a `SymbolContract.State`, which is what I pointed out with `onErrorReturnItem`. At least, for your posted answer it seams it worked for you, although the explicit type shouldn't be necessary since Kotlin could infer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a clean answer:

```
private fun symbols(): Single<SymbolContract.State> =
       symbols.map<SymbolContract.State> { SymbolContract.State.Symbols(it) }
            .onErrorReturnItem(SymbolContract.State.Error(SymbolContract.State.Error.Type.Network))
```

The onErrorReturnItem has to come after the map, and the map needs explicit type parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use global handling error. I give you a sample so you can get the idea. (It is kotlin) and you can catch as many as exception you would like, some of them are my custom exceptions. Just bear in mind, this sample is about Reactive Webflux but you get the idea. It would be similar in others

```
@Configuration
class ExceptionTranslator {

    @Bean
    @Order(-1)
    fun handle(objectMapper: ObjectMapper): ErrorWebExceptionHandler {
        return ErrorWebExceptionHandler { exchange, ex ->
            if (exchange.response.isCommitted) {
                return@ErrorWebExceptionHandler Mono.error(ex)
            }

            val response = exchange.response
            response.statusCode = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
            response.headers.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_PROBLEM_JSON_UTF8

            val url: String

            var message = ex.message
            var params = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()

            when (ex) {
                is ParametricException -> {
                    url = ex.url
                    params = ex.params
                }
                is BaseException -> {
                    url = ex.url
                }
                is BadCredentialsException -> {
                    url = INVALID_CREDENTIAL_TYPE
                    message = ex.message ?: "Wrong Credentials"
                }
                is ConcurrencyFailureException -> {
                    url = INTERNAL_TYPE
                    message = ERR_CONCURRENCY_FAILURE
                }
                is MethodArgumentNotValidException -> {
                    val result = ex.bindingResult
                    val fieldErrors = result.fieldErrors.map {
                        FieldErrorVM(it.objectName, it.field, it.code ?: "Unknown")
                    }

                    url = CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION_TYPE
                    message = ERR_VALIDATION
                    params = Collections.singletonMap("errors", fieldErrors)
                }
                else -> url = INTERNAL_TYPE
            }

            if (ex is BaseException) {
                response.statusCode = HttpStatus.valueOf(ex.status.code())
            }

            val bytes = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(ProblemVM(url, message ?: "Internal Error", params))
            val buffer = response.bufferFactory().wrap(bytes)
            response.writeWith(Mono.just(buffer))
        }
    }

}
```